# How to dynamically name generated PHP table cells

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a weekly calendar application that is part of a webpage I am designing. I want to implement an edit feature which allows the admin the ability to edit the contents of the calendar using textareas in each cell. The calendar is just a table essentially. The table is dynamically generated depending on how many users are in the database. The problem I am having is trying to name each cell properly and then taking the text from that cell and placing it in the correct row in the database

currently I am using a loop to try and dynamically generate a name for each cell using an incrementing variable $i.

```
  for($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++){
        echo "<tr>";
        $q2 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE id='".($i+1)."'");
        $q3 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT lastname FROM users WHERE id='".($i+1)."'");
        $qDays = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE id='".($i+1)."'");
        $rowDays = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qDays);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q3);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q2)){

            $db_firstname = $row['firstname'];
            $db_lastname = $row2['lastname'];

            $sun = $rowDays['sun'];
            $mon = $rowDays['mon'];
            $tue = $rowDays['tue'];
            $wed = $rowDays['wed'];
            $thu = $rowDays['thu'];
            $fri = $rowDays['fri'];
            $sat = $rowDays['sat'];

            echo "<td align='center'> $db_lastname, $db_firstname </td>";
            echo "<td td  height='50px' align='center'><textarea style='height:50px; resize:none; width:100%;'  name='sun.($i+1)'>$sun</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td td  height='50px' align='center'><textarea style='height:50px; resize:none; width:100%;'  name='mon.($i+1)'>$mon</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td td  height='50px' align='center'><textarea style='height:50px; resize:none; width:100%;'  name='tue.($i+1)'>$tue</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td td  height='50px' align='center'><textarea style='height:50px; resize:none; width:100%;'  **name='wed.($i+1)'>$wed</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td td  height='50px' align='center'><textarea style='height:50px; resize:none; width:100%;'  name='thu.($i+1)'>$thu</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td td  height='50px' align='center'><textarea style='height:50px; resize:none; width:100%;'  name='fri.($i+1)'>$fri</textarea></td>";
            echo "<td td  height='50px' align='center'><textarea style='height:50px; resize:none; width:100%;'  name='sat.($i+1)'>$sat</textarea></td>";

        }
```

In the above block from my program, I am trying to dynamically name(by concatinating a string with the variable $i+1) and then populate the text box with the text that is already in the DB.

```
<input style='width:100px;' type='button' value='Confirm Edit' name='edit' class="edit_button">  

<?php
if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
        for($j=0; $j < $srows; $j++){        --srows is the number of rows in the DB
            $sun_post = @$_POST['sun.($j+1)'];
            $mon_post = @$_POST['mon.($j+1)'];
            $tue_post = @$_POST['tue.($j+1)'];
            $wed_post = @$_POST['wed.($j+1)'];
            $thu_post = @$_POST['thu.($j+1)'];
            $fri_post = @$_POST['fri.($j+1)'];
            $sat_post = @$_POST['sat.($j+1)'];
            mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO schedule WHERE id='".($j+1)."' (`id`,`mon`,`tue`,`wed`,`thu`,`fri`,`sat`,`sun`) VALUES ('','".$mon_post."','".$tue_post."','".$wed_post."','".$thu_post."','".$fri_post."','".$sat_post."','".$sun_post."')");
    }

    }
?>




    </body>
```

In this block, I am trying to again get the dynamically generated name by just concatenating a string with the variable $i+1 and inserting the values into the database. My question is how do I correctly dynamically name the textareas so that I can get the data from them to put in the DB and is it possible?

Comment: You aren't actually concatenating. Concatenating would work like this: `'sun'.($j+1)`. Your concatenation can't fall inside of the quotes or else it is just part of the string. If you want the expression `($j+1)` to be evaluated as code, it needs to be outside of the string. Inside of a string, the only "concatenation" type thing that happens is variable substition (replacing `$j` with it's value) and that is only inside of double quotes. If $j has a value of 3, you are literally setting the string `3+1`. Expressions (math, function calls, etc) are not evaluated inside of a string.

Comment: I would use an array in your post something like `name="<?= {$day}[$i] ?>"`

Comment: Both comments helped me get my head around it. I have it working now. I added `$iplus = ($i+1);` and `name='sun{$iplus}'`and `$sun_post = $_POST['sun'.$jplus];`

Answer (score 0):

### Simple solutions

I've solved this same problem many years ago. The only reliable thing you can do, is actually use dates.

```
$startDay = date('N', date('Y-m-01')); // weekdayNum of the first of this month. 

// loop printing empty cells up to the first day in this month

// loop for month starts $day = numerical day this month.
$cellName = "day".$day
```

Ultimately, you need to use a name that is common for every month, in order to simplify the post page. Something like `name="day04"` for the fourth of that month. Then your DB's ID can be a timestamp. This is the only way to do it reliably, and still allow for a calendar that supports more than just one year (as your current method).

For getting that timestamp `ID` just have a couple extra hidden fields storing the year and month of this particular entry.